# How does mysql delete syntax differ from select?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, sql-delete

This:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_playlists, tbl_playlistsongs 
 WHERE tbl_playlists.playlist_id = tbl_playlistsongs.playlist_id 
   AND tbl_playlists.playlist_id = 1
```

...works no problem.  But:

```
DELETE from tbl_playlists, tbl_playlistsongs 
 WHERE tbl_playlists.playlist_id = tbl_playlistsongs.playlist_id 
   AND tbl_playlists.playlist_id = 1
```

...says I have a syntax error. They're identical other than the SELECT * vs DELETE. It still makes perfect logical sense to me.. but I must be missing something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional SQL doesn't support multi-table deletions, but MySQL *does*.  That means you're using MySQL specific syntax:

```
DELETE pl, pls
  FROM TBL_PLAYLISTS pl
  JOIN TBL_PLAYLISTSONGS pls ON pls.playlist_id = pl.playlist_id
 WHERE pl.playlist_id = 1
```

Reference:

- [DELETE (MySQL documentation)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Interesting, never knew MySQL supported join deletes.

Comment: @Kaleb Brasee: [MySQL UPDATE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) as well - too bad it isn't more common, because it's very helpful.

Comment: So you have to use the actual JOIN notation, not just do it associatively (whatever the proper term is...) Very interesting!

Comment: @Damon: ANSI-92 vs ANSI-89 JOIN syntax; ANSI-92 is the preferred syntax, in case you want to use an OUTER JOIN (LEFT, RIGHT) but there's no performance difference.